# Adding custom methods to Iterators in a TreeSet in Java

Tags: java, methods, iterator, treeset

I have a Java `TreeSet`:

```
TreeSet<Integer> tsA = new TreeSet<Integer>();
```

I declare an iterator over this TreeSet as follows:

```
Iterator<Integer> tsAI = tsA.iterator();
```

Now, `tsAI` has methods like `hasNext()` and `next()`. However, I would like to add a custom method along with the original ones in the iterator called `seek(num)` which will place the iterator at the required `num` in the TreeSet.

So say if my `TreeSet` had values `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7)` and I was on 2 and I called `seek(5)` the iterator should jump to 5. How can i do this?

Comment: What do you need this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for, I think, is the [tail set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#tailSet%28E%29).

`tsA.tailSet(5).iterator()` will iterate over all elements in the set greater than or equal to five.

Note that this is not a function of the iterator, but of the set itself.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you want that you should really do is write a static method looking something like `<T> static void advance(Iterator<Integer>, Integer)` that advances another iterator to a specific position.

You might also be able to write an iterator decorator, with which you'd do something like `new MyIterator(treeSet.iterator())` and you could use the additional methods provided by your `MyIterator` class.

What you probably *shouldn't* do is try to subclass `TreeSet` or change the iterators you're getting out of the `TreeSet`.  Instead, operating on top of those iterators or decorating them is the way to go.

Comment: It's hard to wrap this around just any ordinary iterator. If the iterator has already read the 5, which it has to do when you do the seek, it will be one position too far and pointless. No?

Comment: `TreeSet` just gives you "ordinary iterators."  To the extent this is possible at all, it'll be doable this way.  If the OP told us what they actually want to _do_ with this fancy method, we might be able to make more useful suggestions, though.

Comment: Agreed. What I mean, treeset hands you its ordinary iterator, you implement seek() to do next() next() next() until you hit 5. But now you have read too far and next() will yield 7. Not 5. And the iterator has no way to back up one position I think?

Comment: The idea behind this new method was that i should be able to jump to numbers in my tree and as well as call next based on some prior conditions... so like i explained if i called seek(5) it would place me on 5, however if i called seek(6) it would put the iterator on 7 as there is no 6 in the original data...hope this is more helpful...

Comment: @user1950055: There is no way to do that with the `TreeSet` API.  You could get a _new_ iterator at the appropriate position by calling `tailSet(key).iterator()`, though.

Comment: hmmm...okay is there any other tree like data structure i can use where i can do this?

Comment: You can do what you want with `TreeSet`, you just have to create a new fresh iterator (with `tailSet(key).iterator()`) instead of modifying the position of a current one.  That's perfectly fine and efficient; it just involves changing your code slightly.

Comment: okay i will try using that...but what if the key is not present in the treeSet will it automatically progress onto the next key?

Comment: Yes.  That's how `tailSet` works: it's a view of the part of the `TreeSet` that is greater than or equal to the specified key.

Answer (score 0):

not sure this is a good idea or not, but you can start with something like this:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
interface MyIterator extends Iterator {
    void seek(int n);
}
class MyIteratorImpl implements MyIterator {
    @Override public void seek(int n) {
        // ...
    }
    @Override public boolean hasNext() {
        // ...
        return false;
    }
    @Override public Object next() {
        // ...
        return null;
    }
    @Override public void remove() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay...if i did this is there a way for me to maintain the original functionality of hasNext(), next() as i get when i use the base iterator over my TreeSet?

Comment: How would you instantiate the iterator? It's the treeset that hands them out.

Comment: you would need to add a constructor. you might be able to use treesets interator under the hood. if not, you will have to roll your own.